# How do Mapping Templates Work With AWS CDK and AppSync?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-appsync

I am looking to build queries that get one item from the `EmployerAccount` table, and am struggling to understanding what props are required, and their meaning, for `.createResolver`.

**Code:**

```
employerAccountTable.createResolver("QueryEmployerAccount", {
  typeName: "Query",
  fieldName: "addEmployerAccount",
  requestMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbGetItem(appsync.PrimaryKey.partition("id").auto(), appsync.Values.projecting("query"),
  responseMappingTemplate: appsync.MappingTemplate.dynamoDbResultItem(),
});
```

**Questions:**

1. What do all these key/values mean?
2. What would I need to put for the `responseMappingTemplate`? As it is currently underlined red.
3. Have I built the `requestMappingTemplate` correctly?

**Useful Links:**

1. [CDK Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-appsync-alpha.MappingTemplate.html)
2. [@aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-cdk/aws-appsync-alpha) library on npm

Comment: 1) Use the documentation! With an IDEA like VS Code it even shows you directly.
2 & 3 looks good but how about looking on other examples which are working already?